# Adding new items to a variable of type var - Having Constructor and Method declarations in one variable

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I have the following code:

```
var allclasses = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach (var memcls in allclasses)
{
    if (memcls != null)
    {
        var methodDeclarations = memcls.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
        foreach (var memmeth in methodDeclarations)
        {
            var paramDeclaratons = memmeth.ParameterList.Parameters;
```

Right after the line where methodDeclarations is defined, I also want to add a line like the following *pseudo* code:

```
methodDeclarations.AddRange(
    memcls.DescendantNodes().OfType<ConstructorDeclarationSyntax>())
```

In order to have the ConstructorDeclarationSyntax items that are returned added to the same methodDeclarations variable as well; i.e., having both ConstructorDeclarationSyntax and MethodDeclarationSyntax items in the same variable. How can I do that?

I tried some type casting and using List instead of var for methodDeclarations variable, but then it gives errors on the next lines where I want to access ParameterList, Identifier and other properties on memmeth.

As another trick, I tried using the following code

```
var methodDeclarations = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
    .Where(c => c is MethodDeclarationSyntax || c is ConstructorDeclarationSyntax);
```

But then again it gives error on accessing ParameterList and Identifier properties later in the code.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the classes in question. eg what is the common base type of `MethodDeclarationSyntax` and `ConstructorDeclarationSyntax` if you make methodDeclarations a list of that type then you should be able to add them to the same list. Of course if that base class doesn't have a property `ParameterList` then your attempt to access that will fail. What would you expect to happen in this situation?

Comment: These are Roslyn types in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax namespace as mentioned here: http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/9139EA6B.htm
Both MethodDeclarationSyntax and ConstructorDeclarationSyntax  have ParameterList and Identifier properties but their base class BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax ,for instance does not have the Identifier property

Comment: Have you tried `List<BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax> methodDeclarations = ...` as that appears to be the base type?

Comment: Yes, complains on type casting and then gives error when accessing Identifier parameter on them

Comment: Complains about what? What error does it give?

Comment: 'BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax' does not contain a definition for 'Identifier' and no extension method 'Identifier' accepting a first argument of type 'BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
----
ConstructorDeclarationSyntax and MethodDeclarationSyntax  have Identifier property but not the base class.

Comment: If the base class doesn't have the property you want then you'll have to treat them separately since you'll need to cast them to their more specific type to call the property at which point it doesn't seem worth putting them in the same list.

Comment: I believe you *could* use `List<dynamic>` (not that it would be a good idea) and rely on run-time property checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `List<BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax>` as follows:

```
var methods = new List<BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax>();
methods.AddRange(memcls.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>());
methods.AddRange(memcls.DescendantNodes().OfType<ConstructorDeclarationSyntax>());
```

On the methods in that list, you can use all the properties declared on `BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax`, including

- Body
- ExpressionBody
- ParameterList
- ...

But you are right, there is no Identifier property there, for a very simple reason: not every BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax has one. The ones that do have an Identifier property are MethodDeclarationSyntax, ConstructorDeclarationSyntax and DestructorDeclarationSyntax. The ones that don't are OperatorDeclarationSyntax and ConversionOperatorDeclarationSyntax.

You can however easily get the Identifier from those types that have one. Probably the most efficient way to do so is by using a Visitor:

```
internal sealed class IdentifierVisitor : CSharpSyntaxVisitor<SyntaxToken>
{
    public static IdentifierVisitor Instance { get; } = new IdentifierVisitor();

    public override SyntaxToken VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    => node.Identifier;

    public override SyntaxToken VisitConstructorDeclaration(ConstructorDeclarationSyntax node)
    => node.Identifier;

    public override SyntaxToken VisitDestructorDeclaration(DestructorDeclarationSyntax node)
    => node.Identifier;
}
```

Once you have that class, you can get the identifier as follows:

```
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    var identifier = IdentifierVisitor.Instance.Visit(method);

    // for example:
    Console.WriteLine(identifier.Text);
}
```

That would work for regular methods, constructors and destructors.
In a way, it would work for operators and conversion operators too, except that those would return default tokens. So you could do something like:

```
var methods = memcls
    .DescendantNodes()
    .OfType<BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax>()
    .ToList();

foreach (var method in methods)
{
    var identifier = IdentifierVisitor.Instance.Visit(method);

    if (!identifier.IsKind(SyntaxKind.None))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(identifier.Text);
    }
}
```

One final thing: calling .DescendentNodes() will give you every node in the entire ClassDeclarationSyntax tree. You should probably use .Members instead. That would not give you the methods in nested classes (allthough you could easily get those recursively if you need them), but it would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Chris, if the shared base class does not have the appropriate properties you want, you should probably use two separate lists.

However, if you *really* want to use a single list, the following will work:

```
var methodDeclarations =
    tree.GetRoot()
        .DescendantNodes()
        .Where(c => c is MethodDeclarationSyntax || c is ConstructorDeclarationSyntax)
        .Cast<dynamic>();

foreach (var memmeth in methodDeclarations)
{
    // Run-time checking so no syntax error
    Console.WriteLine(memmeth.Identifier);
}
```

Note, however, that this will be less performant as reflection is required and you also lose all the nice static syntax checking that would normally be provided by the compiler.